# Talkback traversal order not kept when using NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, accessibility, android-nestedscrollview, talkback

Talkback order that I want: `title_header` -> `floating_action_button` -> `recycler_view` items (scrolls automatically to `recycler_view` items outside screen).

Observed behavior: `title_header` -> random `recycler_view` item in the middle.

[observed behavior gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8P0qF.gif)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="hello" />
            
            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:accessibilityTraversalAfter="@id/floating_action_button"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

        </LinearLayout>
        
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:accessibilityTraversalAfter="@id/header"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Tried putting `android:importantForAccessibility="no"` in the `NestedScrollView` to solve this issue of the talkback focus going to a random `recycler_view` item in the middle.

New observed behavior: `title_header` -> `floating_action_button` -> `recycler_view` items (**doesn't** automatically scroll to `recycler_view` items outside of screen).

Talkback order that I want: `title_header` -> `floating_action_button` -> `recycler_view` items (scrolls automatically to `recycler_view` items outside screen).

[New observed behavior gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzYcy.gif)

I want to make the talkback focus order behave as described above as well as the talkback focusing automatically scroll the list of `recycler_view` items. How can I achieve this? I am looking forward to hearing your words of wisdom.